# Every run (using pytorch+cuda) is different w/ batch norming, even when RNGs are seeded

Tags: python, pytorch, batch-normalization

Why does my model with batch norm layer behave differently in every running, when the model without batch norm layer performs the same. In my model, random seed has been set by:

```
np.random.seed(args.seed)
torch.manual_seed(args.seed)
random.seed(args.seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(args.seed)
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(args.seed)
```

After removing the batch norm layer and maintaining other settings, my model produces the same results.

Comment: It is better not to put such titles in the question. Please change it.

Comment: The title should describe your actual technical problem. Questions about what questions are on-topic here are off-topic here -- they're only on-topic on [meta]. (Fortunately, you're not actually asking a meta-question, but asking on actual technical question, but your title should describe that technical question; I've tried to edit towards that end).

Comment: The other thing you might add to this is a [mre] that lets someone _test_ whether the output is still random. As-given, the question shows the efforts you've made to avoid randomness, but it doesn't show how someone can see for themselves that those efforts don't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you need to also include the line:

```py
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
```

In order to force the cuda portion of the algorithm to be deterministic in batch norm for PyTorch. [Here are more details](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/8283).